# Can any one suggest a site for beginners to learn cordova + ionic + visual studio to develop mobile apps?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015

I m in need of developing a hybrid mobile application which includes some typical functionalities. I have chose apache cordova + ionic framework + angular js by using visual studio 15. I want to learn how it can be done so can any one suggest me some beginner website for leaning

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, #4: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 1):

While the commenter above is correct (i.e. tutorial recommendations are generally considered relevant in the SO community), here are a few resources you might want to try:

- https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-ionic/
- http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/
- http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/